# ASP.NET MVC4 Unobtrusive validation on demand

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

So I have a form. The form is displayed in a series of steps. More like a step by step wizard.

1. I want to check if the current fields that are displayed (in the current div that is visible in the wizard) have any errors or not. In a way, I want to force validation on a set of fields and see if there are any validation errors
2. Some other related question is that - the validation is triggered as I type. So for an email Address, as soon as I type the first letter, the error message says that the email is invalid. Kind of OK - but kind of distracting. I am wondering if there is a way to postpone validation UNTIL submit button is clicked - or even better an option to whether check on every change or on submit

Answer (score 0):

1. scott gu wrote a pretty good blog early on that uses model validation for mvc models..
   http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx
   some things have been introduced since like razor views but this should be similar if not the same.
2. you would need some java script goodness for this jQuery has a validator plugin that you could look at. http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: OK I figured this out: The validator on the form can be used to 
validate a field 
$("selector").parents('form').validate().element("selector");
the validate() will return a validator object and the element is a function on that object that validates a particular element
What is even more interesting is that this will return a true or false indicating whether the field is OK or not.